# Calling non-static methods in a static method

Tags: c#

I am really stuck in some sort of static-hell that I've placed myself into. I have a server and client. The client asks the server for a list of lobbies. The client creates a graphical lists of buttons for each lobby. Each lobby button has a reference to `Matchmaking`'s static method `JoinLobby` as this seemed the most simple way to hook up `n` amount of lobby buttons.

However after a lobby button calls `JoinLobby` (static) I wanted the `Matchmaking` class to toggle off some UI elements that are `public` but not `static`. I want to avoid making these elements static if possible, because I am using Unity and it breaks the workflow of using Unity's built-in drag-and-drop reference creator.

```
public class LobbyButton{
    public Button button;
    public Text name;
    public void JoinLobby(){
        Matchmaking.JoinLobby(name.text);
    }
}

public class Matchmaking{
   public LobbyList lobbyList; // UI list element

   public static void JoinLobby(string name){
        JoinServerLobby(name);
        lobbyList.Hide(); // can't do this, lobbyList not static
   }
}
```

I've run in to this situation a few times and always end up doing some work-around or total redo. But I am wondering if there is a more common way of "getting out" of this static call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you have something wrong with your design.

Basically `static` means, that current member is a part of type, non an instance, thus mixing them to achieve some result, looks odd.

I think that you should inject `Matchmaking` to the `LobbyButton` button, store it as a field and reference to the non-static `JoinLobby`. I would leave static method to either utility tasks or generic functions, not related to the specific functionality.

Answer (score 2):

> Each lobby button has a reference to Matchmaking's static method JoinLobby as this seemed the most simple way to hook up n amount of lobby buttons.

Don't do that then.

In the form that has the "lobby buttons", keep a private variable with a reference to a `Matchmaking` instance. In the click events, refer to this variable.

You can also use the `Tag` property of buttons to give them an identifier, and hook them all up to the same click handler. There you check the `Tag` of the `sender`.